# .NET MAUI: Unwanted whitespace at bottom of screen using grid layout

Tags: ios, xaml, maui

I have a simple grid layout:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="5*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    
    <Button Grid.Row="0"
            Text="Test1"
            VerticalOptions="Fill"
            BackgroundColor="Green"/>
    

    <Button Grid.Row="1"
            Text="Test2"
            VerticalOptions="Fill"
            BackgroundColor="Red"/>
    
    
</Grid>
```

I expect the red area to extend all the way to the bottom of the screen. However, There's some white space.

[image]

If I change it to a collection view with a footer, it properly fills the bottom section of the screen:

[image]

For reference:

```
<CollectionView>
    <CollectionView.Header>
        <Button 
            Text="Test1"
            VerticalOptions="Fill"
            BackgroundColor="Green"/>

    </CollectionView.Header>
    <CollectionView.EmptyView>
        <Label Text="No items"/>

    </CollectionView.EmptyView>
    <CollectionView.Footer>

        <Button 
            Text="Test2"
            VerticalOptions="Fill"
            BackgroundColor="Red"/>
    </CollectionView.Footer>

</CollectionView>
```

Is there a correct way to fill that bottom "footer" area on a grid view? or without using a collection view?

I don't think it matters but I'm running in iOS simulator on Mac iOS 16.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The white space at the bottom of the screen is `iOS Page UseSafeArea` in **iOS**. However, it is not yet implemented in Maui and you can track the MAUI issue here: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/5856.

As an alternative workaround for now, you can set the `Page Padding` value to remove the bottom white space. In the `OnAppearing` Method, set the `safeInsets` of the page:

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    
    DeviceSafeInsetsService d = new DeviceSafeInsetsService(); 
    double topArea = d.GetSafeAreaTop();
    double bottomArea = d.GetSafeAreaBottom();
    var safeInsets = On<iOS>().SafeAreaInsets();
    safeInsets.Top = -topArea;
    safeInsets.Bottom = -bottomArea;

    Padding = safeInsets;
}
```

And then write `platform specific code` to get the **topArea** and **bottomArea** value.

1.Create `DeviceSafeInsetsService.cs` in Project folder.

```
public partial class DeviceSafeInsetsService
{
    public partial double GetSafeAreaTop();
    public partial double GetSafeAreaBottom();
}
```

2.And then under the **Project/Platform/iOS** folder, create a iOS specific class `DeviceSafeInsetsService.cs`:

```
public partial class DeviceSafeInsetsService
{
    public partial double GetSafeAreaBottom()
    {
        if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(11, 0))
        {
            UIWindow window = UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate.GetWindow();
            var bottomPadding = window.SafeAreaInsets.Bottom;
            return bottomPadding;
        }
        return 0;
    }
    public partial double GetSafeAreaTop()
    {
        if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(11, 0))
        {
            UIWindow window = UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate.GetWindow();
            var TopPadding = window.SafeAreaInsets.Top;
            return TopPadding;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

For more details, you can refer to this sample [.NET MAUI Platform Code Sample](https://github.com/jfversluis/MauiPlatformCodeSample#net-maui-platform-code-sample).

Comment: Thanks! I will try this out. I will need to also create an android partial class too, right? Where I just return zero, if I'm understanding correctly.

Comment: I tried this solution, but the android implementation creates an error since the two classes have the same names. It complains on each method that "Member with the same signature is already declared". I thought this was a super common pattern in Maui!? why is it giving this error?

Comment: I got it working using #if IOS in the iOS partial class and #if !IOS in the android class. I kind of thought the whole reason of maui is to NOT have to use those.. but it works.

Comment: I have researched this a little further, it appears the errors around partial is a bug in Jetbrains Rider. The code above actually works fine in Visual Studio Mac. I have submitted a bug report to Jetbrains. Hopefully they fix it soon.

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to get this to work until I also set `IgnoreSafeArea="True"` on my Layout (which is a `Grid`) which is a container for all of my UI on the page. Once I did that, my Grid filled the screen including the safe area.

This property is mentioned in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/platform-specifics/page-safe-area-layout?view=net-maui-8.0), in the Note in this article.