# .NET MAUI: Unwanted whitespace at bottom of screen in Android

Tags: c#, android, maui

I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74945598/net-maui-unwanted-whitespace-at-bottom-of-screen-using-grid-layout) about the same thing but for iOS. More Android devices have at the bottom of the screen a similar line control than iOS.

[image]

This is an example from my app build with `.NET8` `MAUI`. As you can see, there is a line that as in iOS, allows the user to swipe the app away.

Following the same logic in the other post, I get

```
public partial class DeviceSafeInsetsService
{
    public partial double GetSafeAreaTop();
    public partial double GetSafeAreaBottom();
}
```

Do you know what the implementation could be for Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the default navigation bar for the android. You can put the following code in the `OnCreate` methoed of the **Platforms/Android/MainActivity** to hide it:

```
 protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.Window.DecorView.SystemUiVisibility = (StatusBarVisibility)
                (SystemUiFlags.ImmersiveSticky | SystemUiFlags.HideNavigation |
                 SystemUiFlags.Fullscreen | SystemUiFlags.Immersive);
       // old api without showing hide animation
       //this.Window.InsetsController.Hide( WindowInsets.Type.SystemBars()); 
       //new api with hide animation
    }
```

=================

You can put the following code in the `OnCreate` methoed of the **Platforms/Android/MainActivity** to make the navigation bar transparent:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
   base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
   Window.SetFlags(WindowManagerFlags.LayoutNoLimits, WindowManagerFlags.LayoutNoLimits);
   // this line will make the status bar and navigation bar transparent
   Window.SetStatusBarColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Blue);
  // this line to keep the status bar color
}
```

Comment: OK thank you. Is there a way to keep it and just to add some negative `Padding` like in iOS?

Comment: Please check the update part. @Enrico

Comment: Thank you, I like the transparent navigation bar!